# regexp to catch the last quote in css url

Tags: regex, quote

I'm currently trying to catch the css images url via regexp.
I have this kind of string :

```
#test{background:url(images/prof_01.png);}
#test2{background:url('images/prof_01.png');}
```

I'm using the following exp :

```
/url\(("|')?(.*)("|')?\)/
```

to catch in both cases "images/prof_01.png". My problem is that in the #test2 example, the url comes with its last quote

```
images/prof_01.png'
```

How can I get rid of this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `url\((["']?)(.*?)\1\)` https://regex101.com/r/UOSVAe/1

Comment: Beautiful !! Thanks so much.